# Pidfile exists, but process is dead

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to run my app.js file but when I do a `node app.js status` it sais:

```
Pidfile exists, but process is dead.
```

I have tried re-starting the app.js file but still causing the problem. When I do `node app.js start` is sais it started. And when I do `node app.js stop` is sais it stopped.

But after starting the script and doing `node app.js status` is sais `Pidfile exists, but process is dead.`

I know its not an issue with my code as the same code works fine on another server.

Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by doing:

```
$ sudo kill -9 <app-pid>
$ node app start
```

Comment: If the problem remain after the above solution then run this (sed -i -e 's/\r$//' scriptname.sh). dos to unix.